# Read and Check simple database in a txt file according to user-input

Tags: io, prolog, user-input

I want to create a code which prolog ask for user-input size and compute to get the next input (eg Matric ID) and will check that input in a simple txt file contains student details. So, basically it will read the file and if the id is in the txt file then true if not false. Below is the code:

```
main :-
write('How many people? '),
read(N),
integer(N),
N > 0,
N < 5,
length(L, N),
maplist(read_n, L),
write_list(L),
nl,
open('test.txt',read),
check(N).

read_n(N) :-
  write('Enter id: '),
  read(N),
  integer(N), N >= 10**4, N < 10**5. %the id must be size of 5 and integer
  %if not error message

write_list(L) :-
  write_list(L, 1).

write_list([H|T], N) :-
  nl,
  format('You have entered id ~w: ~w', [N, H]),
  N1 is N + 1,
  write_list(T, N1).

check(N):-
   %to read the file and check if the ID is in the file or not.
   open('test.txt',read,Int),
   read_file(Int,N),
    close(Int),
   write('your ID exist', N), nl.
read_file(Stream,[]):-
     at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_file(Stream,[X|L]):-
     \+  at_end_of_stream(Stream),
     read(Stream,X),
     read_houses(Stream,L).
```

So, basically the data in the file is just a few number with the size of 5 as shown below:

```
16288. Luke. V5G. ICT.
16277. Kristin. V2D. EE.
16177. Catrine. V4E. CV.
16256. Mambo. V1A. MECHE.
15914. Armenio. V5H. PE.
12345. Lampe. V3C. PG.
```

The data in the file is the information of the students. so the prolog will check based on the ID and at the end if the id exist, it will give message of the id details. eg:

```
| ?- main.
Please enter an integer value: 2.
Enter id: 16288.

You have entered id 1: 16288
```

and after that, a message like:
    Welcome Luke. Your room is V5G and you are an ICT students.

Something like that. So, how can I do this function by using Prolog?
Plus, the output is false for the check file. I have tried with a lot of read, see, open file methods but all is futile. T__T

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main`, your `check(N)` call has `N` instantiated as an integer:

```
integer(N),
...
open('test.txt', open),          % <--- this looks like an error
check(N).
```

You also have an extraneous `open/2` call. I'm surprised this didn't generate an error since SWI Prolog doesn't ahve an `open/2`.

In your `check/1` predicate, you have:

```
open('test.txt', read, Int),
read_file(Int, N),
...
```

Based upon your data, you should structure it using Prolog terms in your text file. Note the single quotes around strings that start with a capital letter to make them *atoms*. Otherwise, Prolog will see them as variables.

```
student(16288, 'Luke', 'V5G', 'ICT').
student(16277, 'Kristin', 'V2D', 'EE').
student(16177, 'Catrine', 'V4E', 'CV').
student(16256, 'Mambo', 'V1A', 'MECHE').
student(15914, 'Armenio', 'V5H', 'PE').
student(12345, 'Lampe', V3C, PG).
```

Consult your file as facts at the beginning of your program. Call the file `students.pl`:

```
:- include('students').
```

Then you have a student fact database asserted. `main` then becomes:

```
main :-
    write('How many people? '),
    read(N),
    integer(N),
    N > 0,
    N < 5,
    length(Ids, N),
    maplist(read_n, Ids),
    write_list(Ids),
    check_ids(Ids).

check_ids([Id|Ids]) :-
    (   student(Id, Name, Room, Type)
    ->  format('Welcome ~w. Your room is ~w and you are a ~w student.~n', [Name, Room, Type])
    ;   format('Student id ~w was not found.~n', [Id])
    ),
    check_ids(Ids).
check_ids([]).
```

And just get rid of `read_file`. I would fix `write_list/1` a little so that it succeeds and does your extra `nl` at the end for you:

```
write_list(Ids) :-
    write_list(Ids, 1).

write_list([Id|Ids], N) :-
    format('~nYou have entered id ~w: ~w', [N, Id]),
    N1 is N + 1,
    write_list(Ids, N1).
write_list([], _) :- nl.
```

Comment: I got an error: apply: maplist_/2: Undefined procedure : read_n/1
Exception: (9) read_n(_G2442) ?

Comment: @umika1150 please review my answer as I may have fixed a typo since you grabbed it last. It runs fine for me.

Comment: i should put ':- include('students').' at at the top before 'main:-' right? and 'students.pl' is an external file which I need to save as prolog not txt file right? I've done that but I still got the same error or even more error

Comment: @umika1150 the `include` is a Prolog directive and can really occur anywhere in the file, but often they're included at the beginning. It is also typical to put Prolog fact databases in a Prolog source file. The `include` directive assumes a Prolog source file extension (*e.g.*, `.pl`) when you don't supply it: `:- include('students')` will find `students.pl`. You could use `:- include('students.txt'),` but the facts really are Prolog, so a `.pl` extension is appropriate.